# Can I use interface builder to my fields different positions in landscape mode and portrait mode?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Can I use interface builder to my fields different positions in landscape mode and portrait mode ? (Completely different, so I can't just use the layout properties) ?

Or is the code the only way to go ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method. When you change device orientation it will call..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
  return YES;
}

-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
 {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) 
    {

      [label setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 52, 728, 617)];

    }
     else

    {

    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 52, 728, 617)];

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say go for the code if the fields shared by portrait and landscape mode are same. In case of having different objects in each mode wont  be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep two UIViews in interface builder, and when user rotate device, you can hide one and show another based on orientation. Can you please try the following lines of code?

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if(([self.navigationController.visibleViewController interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || ([self.navigationController.visibleViewController interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
        self.viewLandscape.hidden = NO;
        self.viewPortrait.hidden = YES;
    }
    else {
        self.viewLandscape.hidden = YES;
        self.viewPortrait.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the approaches that you can use. Best approach is on the top

**1.** It's better to use auto layout for adjusting your views.

**2.** Auto layout + code

**3.** Code only.

**4.** You can make two views for your xib one for landscape and one for portrait. And show and hide as per the orientation. But in this you need to sync all your portrait views with landscape views (properties like text) and vice versa. This is easy to maintain but you have to take extra headache for syncing the properties of each view.